# How to translate an Enum dynamically in Spring?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

New at Spring! I'm trying to translate an Enum like Gender dynamically but I do not find how. Let say I have a gender object...

> public enum Gender {
>         FEMALE, 
>         MALE;
>       }

And I have a Controller that will use it to fill a jsp, like this....

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit-profile-about3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView editProfileAbout3(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

            SiteUser user = getUser();

            Profile profile = profileService.getUserProfile(user);

            Profile webProfile = new Profile();
            webProfile.safeCopyFrom(profile);

            List<Gender> gender = new ArrayList<Gender>(EnumSet.allOf(Gender.class));
           modelAndView.getModel().put("gender", gender);
           modelAndView.setViewName("app.editprofileabout3");
            return modelAndView;
        }
```

Now **I would like to show not the values MALE and FEMALE uppercase like they show up from the Enum, but like Male and Female in English or Hombre and Mujer in Spanish in my JSP**:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="profile" class="sky-form" id="sky-form4">

                                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                        <dt>Gender:</dt>
                                        <dd>
                                            <form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${gender}" />
                                        </dd>
                                    </dl>
<button class="btn-u btn-u-default" type="button" value="Cancel">Cancelar</button>
<button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">Guardar</button>
</form:form>`
```

How can I do it? I think it is not a properties internationalization since the jsp charges dynamically the form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${gender}" with MALE FEMALE and I want that to be translated before it gets to the JSP (in other words, I can not use a properties to translate both Enums at the same time, right? When I get the answer to my POST Controller I want to get MALE, FEMALE, but may be show Hombre, Mujer (translation). 
Thanks

Comment: In other words, you need to internationalize Spring MVC app. Here is one of the examples: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: Are you sure? Can I translate all the Enums when I use form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${gender}"? Thanks

Comment: JSP is being rendering on the server side and during this process it's possible to get the translation from properties to return to a user a page that has already translated items.

Comment: How? I have this form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${gender}. Following your example....  Should I use items="welcome.springmvc.gender.male" and items="welcome.springmvc.gender.female" ? putting two lines, one for each Enum

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#enum)

> 1.12  Serialization of Enum Constants
>
> Enum constants are serialized differently than ordinary serializable
>   or externalizable objects. The serialized form of an enum constant
>   consists solely of its name; field values of the constant are not
>   present in the form. To serialize an enum constant, ObjectOutputStream
>   writes the value returned by the enum constant's name method. To
>   deserialize an enum constant, ObjectInputStream reads the constant
>   name from the stream; the deserialized constant is then obtained by
>   calling the java.lang.Enum.valueOf method, passing the constant's enum
>   type along with the received constant name as arguments. Like other
>   serializable or externalizable objects, enum constants can function as
>   the targets of back references appearing subsequently in the
>   serialization stream.
>
> The process by which enum constants are serialized cannot be
>   customized: any class-specific writeObject, readObject,
>   readObjectNoData, writeReplace, and readResolve methods defined by
>   enum types are ignored during serialization and deserialization.
>   Similarly, any serialPersistentFields or serialVersionUID field
>   declarations are also ignored--all enum types have a fixed
>   serialVersionUID of 0L. Documenting serializable fields and data for
>   enum types is unnecessary, since there is no variation in the type of
>   data sent.

So, if the [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is just being serialized, you have to change the Enum name to the casing you want (all caps is just the convention). If the Enum is just getting converted to a string, than Enum acts just like a class, so you can just Override the toString method like this. (and constructor and value holder)

```
public static enum GENDER {
    MALE("Male", "Hombre"), FEMALE("Female", "Mujer");

    GENDER (String en, String sp) {
        en_value = en;
        sp_value = sp;
    }

    private String en_value;
    private String sp_value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return en_value;
    }

    public String toEnglish() {
        return en_value;
    }

    public String toSpanish() {
        return sp_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Miguel wants it to be translated also. Most likely the approach with `toString()` won't work in this case.

Comment: Can you explain how it will show (in lowercase) in the Controller and the JSP, please? Do you have any documentation? Thanks

Comment: @Miguel Added more information. The Serialization works differently than I thought, so the 'right' way depends on whether GENDER is serialized or stringified. Just changing the Enum name works in both cases though.

Comment: @Tezra. Thanks, but can you be more specific with your example? Explaining the Controller and the JSP too (with the case of Male=Hombre and Female=Mujer)

Comment: @Miguel I can't run this to test, and I can't tell if [@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) serializes the data, or just converts it to a string... But you should probably only pass a string, and have a translation key (either server or client side) that converts the key value to the appropriate user language.